How can I capture photo / video in WebXR threejs?
I want to capture photo / video while in AR mode . I am using webxr of threejs for the AR mode.
I tried to take photos but it gave me black photos.
I tried it using getUserMedia
I don't know whether I can use the same stream that webxr is using in AR mode.
I want to capture the camera stream that is being present in the AR mode and three Objects in that scene and capture photos/videos simultaneously.
Looking for a solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Haven't worked with WebXR before, but I assume it paints on a canvas element? If so, then you could get a stream for the canvas with captureStream and capture an image with the Media Image Capture API.
